# How do I customize the display of column headers in my WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controltemplate, contentpresenter

I am trying to customize a DataGrid.  I want to insert some content above the column headers.  I am trying to use the ControlTemplate to do this.  I have my XAML code below.  My problem is that the `<ContentPresenter />` is not outputting anything.  When I load the page, the `after` TextBlock appears directly below the `before` TextBlock with nothing in between.  I want to display the column headers in that space.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    <DataGrid.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock>before</TextBlock>
                <ContentPresenter /> <!-- outputs nothing -->
                <TextBlock>after</TextBlock>                        
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Template>

</DataGrid>
```

How do I display the column headers between the `before` TextBlock and the `after` TextBlock?  My List object is simply a BindingList of some generic class that has a couple of public properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.  I should use `<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter />` instead of `<ContentPresenter />`.  So my code that works looks like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    <DataGrid.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock>before</TextBlock>
                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter />
                <TextBlock>after</TextBlock>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>                        
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Template>

</DataGrid>
```